# call jquery focus from JSNI method inside GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

How can I set focus from JSNI method for a field in GWT application that I know its ID?
For example suppose I have this method:

```
public native void focusOn(String id) /*-{
    $wnd.$("#" + id).focus();
}-*/;
```

This is not working. Are there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether `$wnd.$("#" + id)` is providing access to the field you need?

Comment: No I have not, how can I do that?

Comment: What is that `field in gwt`, is a gwt widget? which widget class? how do you instantiate it and attach to the dom?

Comment: I guess you run your select before the element is attached to the dom.